# Synching UISlider and UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uislider

Currently I have a UISlider that is linked to the ScrollView. Once I drag the slider it moves the scrollview.

However the ScrollView doesn't move the slider

Any Ideas on how I can sync the both would be much appreciated

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is the frame of uislider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
 slider.maximumValue =ScrollView.contentSize.height;
```

set content offset for ScrollView

```
-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    UISlider * slider = (UISlider*)sender;
    ScrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0,[slider value]);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  slider.value=scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Comment: From the description, the OP already has this part. Getting the content offset change on scroll and passing it to the slider is what's required.

Comment: I've used the following code, still no luck.. 
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    slider.value = mainScroll.contentOffset.y;
    
}

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean with "ScrollView doesn't move the slider". Do you want to change slider's value? Or do you want to change slider's position?

If you want to change slider's value according to scroll view's content offset, implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` method in delegate of your scroll view and set slider's value there.